# Error while downloading PETSc and SLEPc with cygwin

Tags: bash, cygwin, petsc

I try to install PETSc and SLEPc with cygwin on Windows following a manual. It says:

```
mkdir petsc
mkdir slepc
git clone -b maint https://bitbucket.org/petsc/petsc petsc
git clone -b maint https://bitbucket.org/slepc/slepc slepc
cd petsc
export CYGWIN=winsymlinks:native
export PETSC_DIR=~/petsc
export PETSC_ARCH=win64-cygwin-debug

./configure -–with-fc=0 --download-superlu --download-metis \--download-parmetis --download-ptscotch
```

But when I execute the last step there is an error which says:

```
UNABLE to CONFIGURE with GIVEN OPTIONS    (see configure.log for details):
----------------------------------------------------------
Error running make on PARMETIS
```

Looking into configure.log didn't help me. An excerpt of the document:

```
********************************************************
         UNABLE to CONFIGURE with GIVEN OPTIONS    (see configure.log for details):
--------------------------------------------------------
Error running make on  PARMETIS
********************************************************
  File "/home/Salih/petsc/config/configure.py", line 447, in petsc_configure
    framework.configure(out = sys.stdout)
  File "/home/Salih/petsc/config/BuildSystem/config/framework.py", line 1195, in configure
    self.processChildren()
  File "/home/Salih/petsc/config/BuildSystem/config/framework.py", line 1184, in processChildren
    self.serialEvaluation(self.childGraph)
  File "/home/Salih/petsc/config/BuildSystem/config/framework.py", line 1159, in serialEvaluation
    child.configure()
  File "/home/Salih/petsc/config/BuildSystem/config/package.py", line 1088, in configure
    self.executeTest(self.configureLibrary)
  File "/home/Salih/petsc/config/BuildSystem/config/base.py", line 139, in executeTest
    ret = test(*args,**kargs)
  File "/home/Salih/petsc/config/BuildSystem/config/packages/parmetis.py", line 42, in configureLibrary
    config.package.Package.configureLibrary(self)
  File "/home/Salih/petsc/config/BuildSystem/config/package.py", line 866, in configureLibrary
    for location, directory, lib, incl in self.generateGuesses():
  File "/home/Salih/petsc/config/BuildSystem/config/package.py", line 444, in generateGuesses
    d = self.checkDownload()
  File "/home/Salih/petsc/config/BuildSystem/config/package.py", line 578, in checkDownload
    return self.getInstallDir()
  File "/home/Salih/petsc/config/BuildSystem/config/package.py", line 340, in getInstallDir
    installDir = self.Install()
  File "/home/Salih/petsc/config/BuildSystem/config/package.py", line 1718, in Install
    raise RuntimeError('Error running make on  '+self.PACKAGE)
========================================================
Finishing configure run at Wed, 12 Jan 2022 22:45:42 +0300
========================================================
```

What could be the reason for this error?

Comment: It is definitely not a very helpful error message.  I looked at [the code](https://bitbucket.org/petsc/petsc/src/c5062165eaea29bbd7d3d8f666a35def24688e37/config/BuildSystem/config/package.py#lines-1714) where this exception is being raised and it is...well let's just say it needs a dedicated software engineer to spend a month or two cleaning it up.  It looks like it is very old though (the code makes reference to Python 1!!!)  I would be amazed if it works on cygwin at all.

Comment: Try editing that file and add above line 1713 a line with `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` to see if you can get it to drop into a debugger.  Then step through it line-by-line by pressing `n` and see which line is actually raising the original exception.

Comment: I also noticed you're installing it from bitbucket, but at the top of their bitbucket repo is a note that they've migrated the repository to gitlab (the one in bitbucket seems a bit old): https://gitlab.com/petsc/petsc